# Why is this jQuery animation jumping up and down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

CSS is more or less irrelevant. How do I stop jumping?

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#showquickfind").mouseover(function() {
    jQuery("#quickfind").animate({
      height: "show",
      opacity: "show"
    }, "slow");
    return false;
  });
  jQuery("#quickfind").hover(function() {},
    function() {
      $("#quickfind").animate({
        opacity: 1.0
      }, 1125).slideUp(375);
      return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="showquickfind">show me</a>

<div id="quickfind">
  <ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show an image or include a link with the live code? Hard to tell what you mean by jump.

Comment: @Dave- have set up Frank's code on a link on my answer. I've highlighted the div border too, to make things easier

Comment: As a matter of fact, the test code works perfectly in Safari and Firefox for me.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at chaining the [jQuery.stop()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop#clearQueuegotoEnd) command before each animate command. It stops all the currently running animations on the specified elements.
i.e.

```
jQuery("#quickfind").stop().animate({ 
    height:"200px", opacity: 1},"slow"); 
    return false;
```

Is there a reason you are using jQuery instead of the shorthand $ for the jQuery object? you can use the $ shorthand for the jQuery object, even if using other libraries that use it, by following this pattern-

```
(function($) {

//Your code here using $ shorthand for jQuery :)

})(jQuery);
```

This means that $ within the scope of the outer function is a reference for the jQuery object.

I have set up [your code on this sample page](http://jsbin.com/oluqe). If you want to edit it, then add "/edit" to the URL.

Also, Are you sure that "show" is a valid value for height and opacity?

My understanding is that *height* needs to be set to either auto(i.e. size of containing block), a length or a percentage relative to the containing block, and *opacity* should be a value between 0 and 1 (jQuery abstracts away differences between browsers and will use whichever opacity attribute is appropriate *i.e.* opacity *or* filter:alpha(opacity))

Comment: yes, that project uses legacy prototype code along with new jquery

Answer (score 1):

You have the same problem I did.  What's happening is that your hover event happens, the quickfind slides up, but then it disappears, so it shows again, etc, etc, etc.

The only way I've found to make it stop jumping is to keep a height set on the container element, so that it always stays that height.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `mouseenter` event, not `mouseover`.

The difference is described in [the jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseover).

> **Mouseover** fires when the pointer moves *into or out from child element*, while **mouseenter** doesn't.

There's also the example how to use it, you have to use the `bind()` function.

**Edit**

After all the best solution could be to use [`hover()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover), as Russ Cam has mentioned in the comments.

**BTW**

You're registering the hover-handle multiple times, each time one goes over the "show me"-link.

Comment: Good call - Is mouseenter a new event for 1.3.1? It appears to be the same implementation and effect as the hover command from 1.2.6